# Magento2 B2B whole Seller Extension recommendation

Tags: extensions, sellers-dashboard, magento2-b2b

Currently I have `B2C` website where a customer can place order as a guest 
Now I want to integrate `B2B` there where a whole-seller or retailer can only see a product when He is logged in.
Do I need to create a different store view for it?
Also I need recommendation for whole-seller `B2B Extension` which is not much costly?

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this  [B2B extension](https://www.iwdagency.com/extensions/b2b-ecommerce-suite-m1-m2.html?utm_source=mageplaza&utm_medium=mageplaza&utm_campaign=mageplaza-review&utm_content=Wholesale)